# jQuery animate height during .show('slide')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know if someone can help me with this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/wMck2/7/

```
$(".turn_next").click(function(){
   $(".box2").hide();
   $(".box3").animate({height:'300px'}, 300);
   $(".box3").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
});

$(".turn_back").click(function(){
   $(".box3").hide();
   $(".box2").animate({height:'100px'}, 300);
   $(".box2").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
});
```

I want that before the slide transition between box2 (the red one) and box3 (the yellow one) the user could see the height animation because the height of both are different.

Any idea?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Is it just me or isn't that demo doing anything useful?

Comment: Demo updated: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/wMck2/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need this?

```
$(".turn_next").click(function(){
   $(".box2").hide();
   $(".box1_content").animate({height:'300px'}, 300,function(){
         $(".box3").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
   });
});

$(".turn_back").click(function(){
   $(".box3").hide();
   $(".box1_content").animate({height:'100px'}, 300,function(){
       $(".box2").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
   });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jx3n/1/)